# How to see s, p, d, and other band in the band diagram? Is it possible?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, metals, magnetic-moment

I am reading this [book](https://www.amazon.de/Electronic-Properties-Materials-Rolf-Hummel/dp/1441981632), to understand magnetism in material.

It is stated there that the d-bands overlap the next higher s-band.

I am aware about Hund's rule.

How to see that in the band diagram? Is it even possible?

[image: quote]

[image: Fig. 5.22]

edited figure.
[image: edit]

Comment: You can see a free-electron-like band going up from $\Gamma$ at 0 eV.  Then there are avoided crossings, but it continues beyond the Fermi level.

Comment: I upload a new edited picture of the band diagram.
I tried to understand the part of the diagram that you refered. I dont know whether I locate them correctly:
"You can see a free-electron-like band going up from ΓΓ at 0 eV" --> 1
" Then there are avoided crossings" --> 3
"but it continues beyond the Fermi level." --> 2

Still I do not see what the text is trying to say.

Comment: Yes, 1) and 2) are parts of a free-electron-like dispersion. In the empty-lattice these would be plane waves, but in copper they are mostly composed of $4s,\ 4p$ and higher orbitals. The $3d$ orbitals have less overlap with $3d$ orbitals on neighboring sites, so less dispersion.

Comment: Thank you. Would you like to put your answer in the answer area so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see a free-electron-like band going up from Γ at 0 eV (at your mark "1"). Then there are avoided crossings (for example at "3"), but it continues beyond the Fermi level (near "2").

The bands near "1" and "2" are parts of a free-electron-like dispersion. In the empty-lattice these would be plane waves, but in copper they are mostly composed of $4s, 4p$ and higher orbitals. The $3d$ orbitals have less overlap with $3d$ orbitals on neighboring sites, so less dispersion.

(But that calculation by Segal from 1962 is a bit old now. Better to use a state-of-the-art *ab initio* calculation.)